# vue2 set timeout problem and token reissue time

Tags: javascript, vue.js, settimeout

When you are on the same page for more than 14 minutes, you will be asked if you want to reissue the token. If you reissue, you will get your token back and if you hit no you will be logged out. If you do not issue tokens for more than 15 minutes, you will be logged out as well.

But the timer is not initialized even if it goes to another page. And it asks for token issuance only once per page. After reissuing tokens in 15 minutes, you will not be asked again even after 1 hour has passed.

I'm new to writing this kind of code, so I'm not sure what the problem is.

How can I reset the time when moving the page and show a token reissue alert every 14 minutes?

```
<div id="demo"></div>
.
.
.

    export default {
            data() {
                return {
                    isActive: false,
                    active: 'main',
                    activeSidebar: false,
                    // logout_page: false,
                    userId: '',
                };
            },
        
            methods: {
                logout: function () {
                    console.log('Logout');
                    store.dispatch('authLogout');
                    store.commit('setLoginCheck', false);
                    this.$router.push('/login'); // page move
                },
            },
            watch: {
                $route(to, from) {
                    const loginCheck = store.getters.loginCheck;
                    const tokenData = store.getters.tokenData;
        
                    console.log('tokenData : ' + loginCheck);
                    
                    var time = 900; // Create standard time 15 ★
                    var min = '';
                    var sec = ''; 
                    var x = null;
        
                    if (
                        store.getters.tokenData !== 'N' &&
                        store.getters.tokenData !== null &&
                        store.getters.tokenData !== undefined &&
                        store.getters.tokenData == true
                    ) {
                        console.log('set time out');
  
                        x = setTimeout(function () {
                            
                            min = parseInt(time / 60); //calculate the share
                            sec = time % 60; // calculate the rest
        
                            document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = min  + sec ;
                            time--;
        
                            //time out
                            if (time < 0) {
                                clearTimeout(x); // setInterval() ends execution
                                document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = ' timeout';
                            }
                        }, 1000);
                    } else {
                        clearTimeout(x);
                        clearTimeout(tokenTime);
                    }
        
                    function tokenTime() {
                        store.dispatch('tokenCheck');
        
                        if (tokenData !== 'N') {
                            if (
                                !confirm(
                                    ' Do you want to extend your tokens?',
                                )
                            ) {
                                alert('Canceled token issuance');
                                store.dispatch('authLogout');
                                clearTimeout(x);
                                clearTimeout(tokenTime);
                                router.push('/login'); //  page move
                            } else {
                                store.dispatch('tokenCheck');
                                if (tokenData == 'N' && confirm) {
                                    alert('.Canceled token issuance');
                                    store.dispatch('authLogout');
                                    clearTimeout(x);
                                    clearTimeout(tokenTime);
                                    console.log(tokenData);
                                    router.push('/login'); //  page move
                                    router.go();
                                } else if (tokenData !== 'N' && confirm) {
                                    alert('Tokens have been extended');
                                    console.log(tokenData);
                                    clearTimeout(x);
                                    clearTimeout(tokenTime);
                                    // router.go();
                                }
                            }
                        } else {
                            alert('Canceled token issuance');
                            store.dispatch('authLogout');
                            clearTimeout(x);
                            clearTimeout(tokenTime);
                            console.log(tokenData);
                            router.push('/login'); //  page move
                            router.go();
                        }
                    }
                    if (to.path != from.path) {
                        store.dispatch('tokenCheck');
                        if (
                            loginCheck === true &&
                            loginCheck === !null &&
                            loginCheck === !undefined
                        ) {
                            clearTimeout(x);
                            clearTimeout(tokenTime);
                            store.dispatch('tokenCheck');
                            console.log('loginCheck : ' + loginCheck);
                            setTimeout(() => tokenTime(), 140000); //14★
                        } else {
                            alert('There are no tokens.');
                            clearTimeout(x);
                            clearTimeout(tokenTime);
                            store.dispatch('authLogout');
                            this.$router.push('/login'); // page move
                        }
                    }
                },
            },
        };
```

Comment: can't see any code that references 14 or 15 minutes at all

Comment: @JaromandaX
It's corrected. I put a star next to the hour...!

Comment: 140000 is not 14 minutes ... it's 2 minutes 20 seconds ...

Comment: @JaromandaX The time seems to have been set short to facilitate testing. The important thing is that no matter how many minutes it takes, that code doesn't work well.

Comment: yeah, OK, the code is very (over) complicated, so I was asking to get some sort of handle on what it is your code is trying to do (as opposed to what you're trying to achieve, which you have explained well enough)